# How to find a React component inside an element with specific class using enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a React component using Jest and Enzyme. I want to simulate a click event on a Button component which is inside a div with a specific class name. I can't retrieve the Button node.

I have the following markup in my component

```
<div className="settings">
    <Button
        onClick={() => this.toggleSettingsModal(true)}
        buttonStyle={ButtonStyle.Primary}>
        Settings
    </Button>
</div>
```

I have tried

```
const component = shallow(<MyComponent />);
component.find(".settings[Button]").simulate("click");
```

I expect to find the Button component, but I get `0` nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
    it('simulates click events', () => {
        const component = shallow(<MyComponent />);
        component.find(Button).simulate("click");
    });
});
```

**EDIT**
Try the code below:

```
expect(component
        .find(Button)
        .closest('.settings'))
        .simulate("click");
```

Comment: This would work if I had only one Button component. Alternatively I would have to write something like `component.find(Button).at(3).simulate("click");`. This is not ideal because I would have to change this test every time the order of my Button changes. I wanted a more specific way of retrieving the button, thus, this still doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

The type of element isn't a `Button`, thats the component name. It is probably a `button` or `input`. You can do it like this depending on what element type the node is:

```
const foo = shallow(<MyComponent />);
foo.find(".settings[button]").simulate("click");
```

To make this more specific you could always add a class to the button.

Or, [per the documentation](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html), if you'd like to you can target it by inputting the component to the test and then finding it that way:

```
import Bar from '../components/Foo';

const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
wrapper.find(Bar).simulate("click");
```

Finally, without any additional imports you can use the display name of the component like so:

```
const baz = shallow(<MyComponent />);
baz.find('Button').simulate("click");
```