# Find component element by name in jest enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, babel-jest

component:

```
<input name="search" onChange={this.onChange}>

console.log(component.find('div').at(0).childAt(0).find('input').find('search').debug())
```

error:

doesn't show anything

Comment: will this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451529/how-to-find-a-react-component-inside-an-element-with-specific-class-using-enzyme

Comment: no. I want to find only by name. is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find components by specifying their properties which is called as **Object Property Selector**. Please find details [here](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html).

As you said you want to find component using `name` property then please try this:

```
component.find({ name: "search" }).debug();
```